# How to get MemoryDistributedCache in scope of user Action?

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, session-state

We create MemoryDistributedCache  instance in `Statup.ConfigureServices` using

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddSession();
```

But how to access it scope of user action? E.g. administrator have changed user privileges and we should reset some sessions users data (privileges) stored there.

Comment: Did you try to inject `IDistributedCache`? Because this extension method just registers `IDistributedCache`. See https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/efbbdc5e0a8c8a664ea34cd41220d084b6906f57/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCacheServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L76

Comment: @ademcaglin  Thank you. This should be a correct move. How I can inject it? In controllers constructor?

Comment: Yes, you can inject it with controller constructor.

Comment: @ademcaglin, thank you, it works. May be you can reply on more geniral quesiton? How to get from container information which interfaces can be injected through constructor? It is now like a hidden part of api..